# Bad file descriptor socket.recv error & solution but I don't know why

Tags: python, sockets

Here is the serve code:

```
from socket import *
from time import ctime

HOST = ''
PORT = 21567
BUFSIZ = 1024
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)

tcpSerSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
tcpSerSock.bind(ADDR)
tcpSerSock.listen(5)

try:
    while True:
        print 'Wait for connection...'
        tcpCliSock, addr = tcpSerSock.accept()
        print '...connnet from:', addr

        while True:
            data = tcpCliSock.recv(BUFSIZ)
            if not data:
                break
            tcpCliSock.send('[%s] %s' % (ctime(), data))
            tcpCliSock.close()
except (EOFError, KeyboardInterrupt):
    tcpSerSock.close()
```

Here is the client code:

```
from socket import *

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 21567
BUFSIZ = 1024
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)

tcpCliSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
tcpCliSock.connect(ADDR)

while True:
    data = raw_input(">")
    if not data:
        break
    tcpCliSock.send(data)

    data = tcpCliSock.recv(BUFSIZ)
    if not data:
        break
    print data
    break

tcpCliSock.close()
```

When I run serve code, it shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/python/tcpServ&tcpClnt/tsTserv.py", line 22, in <module>
    data = tcpCliSock.recv(BUFSIZ)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 170, in _dummy
    raise error(EBADF, 'Bad file descriptor')
socket.error: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

But client could still get the information. Then I changed the code in socket.py, it worked! But I don't know why.

PS. I changed:

```
class _closedsocket(object):
    __slots__ = []
    def _dummy(*args):
        raise error(EBADF, 'Bad file descriptor')
```

to this:

```
class _closedsocket(object):
    __slots__ = []
    def _dummy(*args):
        pass
```

Comment: Check your server code, HOST = '  ', why there is no IP or hostname here?

Comment: @pmverm The empty HOST could bind 'bind()' to all the effective addresses

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because you call `recv()` of the afore closed socket. Sequence of execution:

```
        …
            data = tcpCliSock.recv(BUFSIZ)  # data from tcpCliSock.send(data) is received
# not true: if not data:
# skipped:      break
            tcpCliSock.send('[%s] %s' % (ctime(), data))    # reply data is sent to client
            tcpCliSock.close()                              # the socket is closed!
        while True:                                         # the loop is reiterated
            data = tcpCliSock.recv(BUFSIZ)                  # the closed socket is used!
```

Perhaps you just by mistake indented the `tcpCliSock.close()` wrongly. If you outdent it, all works:

```
        while True:
            data = tcpCliSock.recv(BUFSIZ)
            if not data:
                break
            tcpCliSock.send('[%s] %s' % (ctime(), data))
        tcpCliSock.close()
```

> Then I changed the code in socket.py, it worked! But I don't know why.

By changing `raise …` to `pass`, you just swept the error under the carpet.